# Magento 2: How to sort order of custom links nav?

Tags: magento2, module, blocks, topmenu

I've used following code to insert custom links in topmenu.

But those are coming in the last of main nav. I want first about us then some other category then contacts us etc.

```
<?php 

namespace Dcw\Customer\Plugin\Block;

use Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\NodeFactory;

class Topmenu
{
    /**
     * @var NodeFactory
     */
    protected $nodeFactory;

    public function __construct(
        NodeFactory $nodeFactory
    ) {
        $this->nodeFactory = $nodeFactory;
    }

    public function beforeGetHtml(
        \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu $subject,
        $outermostClass = '',
        $childrenWrapClass = '',
        $limit = 0
    ) {
        $node = $this->nodeFactory->create(
            [
                'data' => [
            'name' => __('ABOUT US'),
            'id' => 'aboutus',
            'url' => 'http://www.example.com/',
            'has_active' => true,
            'is_active' => true // (expression to determine if menu item is selected or not)
        ],
                'idField' => 'id',
                'tree' => $subject->getMenu()->getTree()
            ]
        );
        $subject->getMenu()->addChild($node);
        $node = $this->nodeFactory->create(
            [
                'data' => [
            'name' => __('CONTACT US'),
            'id' => 'contactus',
            'url' => 'http://www.example.com/',
            'has_active' => true,
            'is_active' => true // (expression to determine if menu item is selected or not)
        ],
                'idField' => 'id',
                'tree' => $subject->getMenu()->getTree()
            ]
        );
        $subject->getMenu()->addChild($node);
        $node = $this->nodeFactory->create(
            [
                'data' => [
            'name' => __('CATALOG DOWNLOAD'),
            'id' => 'catalogdownload',
            'url' => 'http://www.example.com/',
            'has_active' => true,
            'is_active' => true // (expression to determine if menu item is selected or not)
        ],
                'idField' => 'id',
                'tree' => $subject->getMenu()->getTree()
            ]
        );
        $subject->getMenu()->addChild($node);
    }


}
```

Comment: thanks for shearing the code in the question, It is just what i was looking for :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**A little bit code modification is need in  your code.**

Open your `di.xml` then put `sortOrder="-1"`

Using this `sortOrder="[NumericValue]"` tag you can arrange sequesce  of execution of plugin for the same method.

> plugin sortOrder: The order in which plugins that call the same method
>   are run.
>   see
>   http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

**Reason:**

Magento adds categories in the menu using [a plugin of same class](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/etc/di.xml#L69) at **Magento_Catalog**.

```
 <type name="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu">
     <plugin name="catalogTopmenu" type="Magento\Catalog\Plugin\Block\Topmenu" /> 
 </type>
```

So should run your plugin before that default plugin `catalogTopmenu`, 
we know that sequence of plugins can manage from **sortOrder** field,

That you need put ***sortOrder of your plugin*** in negative than `catalogTopmenu`.

Also if you don't put sort order in **plugin** then it means **sortOrer** value should be `0`.

That reason, I'm suggesting to put sortOrder value  -1.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `addChild` function of class `\Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node` don't process position somehow, so it is why adding nodes just before rendering will append them to the already set nodes.

```
/**
 * Add child node
 *
 * @param   Node $node
 * @return  Node
 */
public function addChild($node)
{
    $this->_childNodes->add($node);
    return $this;
}
```

If one could save temporarily existing nodes in a variable and reappend nodes in the wanted order

```
$children = $subject->getMenu()->getChildren();
//then delete them using removeChild() (one by one) or by creating a new parent node

//add here your first childNode
foreach ($children as $child) {
    $this->addChild($child);
}
//add here your last custom childNode
```

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use Observer in this case.

**vendor/magento/module-theme/Block/Html/Topmenu.php**

`page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_before` and `page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_after` are the events that you need to use.

Answer (score -2):

I think this is the easiest way you can add links in your top menu.

Override the topmenu.phtml file in your theme like this:

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/Magento_Theme/templates/html/topmenu.phtml
```

and add this code:

```
<?php $columnsLimit = $block->getColumnsLimit() ?: 0; ?>
<?php $_menu = $block->getHtml('level-top', 'submenu', $columnsLimit) ?>
<?php $_custom_menu_before = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('before_topmenu')->toHtml();?>
<?php $_custom_menu_after = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('after_topmenu')->toHtml();?>

<nav class="navigation" data-action="navigation">
    <ul data-mage-init='{"menu":{"responsive":true, "expanded":true, "position":{"my":"left top","at":"left bottom"}}}'>
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_custom_menu_before; ?>
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_menu; ?>
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getChildHtml(); ?>
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_custom_menu_after; ?>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Then you will create two blocks in Admin with your custom links:

before_topmenu

after_topmenu

Hope it helps!

Comment: Not a good approach to override templates and create CMS blocks inside *.phtml files.